# mapping one model to another model in service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi Team kindly help me with the scenario like in my function iam sending my model object 1 with that i want to map to another model object which is alredy created in service layer

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question, you will get much better answers if you provide code. Add what you have tried so far. Also please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a good and well-received question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ModelMapper or MapStruct library for Object Mapping. I prefer ModelMapper one.

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper ();
YourClassType obj = mapper.map(object1, YourClassType.class);
```